# Relative angle in degrees between 2 lines

Tags: vector, angles

[image: example]

Could anybody help to solve this? Relative angle between 2 rays(lines) which starts from same point. They could point anywhere 360 clockwise, but angle should be always relative (just inside angle).

Answer (score 3):

[Did you try even a cursory search for this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=angle%20between%20two%20vectors)? It's pretty standard vector math:

```
v1 = normalize(end1X - startX, end1Y - startY);
v2 = normalize(end2X - startX, end2Y - startY);

angle = acos(dot(v1, v2)) * 180.0/pi;
```

This will always give a value from 0 to 180, giving you the smallest positive angle clockwise or counter-clockwise.

In 2D, you can fix a rotation direction like so:

```
v1perp = (-v1.y, v1.x);

if(dot(v2, v1perp) > 0)
    angle = 360.0 - angle;
```

This will give a clockwise angle in the range 0...180 if v2 points to the right of v1, or 180...360 if v2 is pointing to the left of v1.

Comment: I know that Google would fill in the blanks, but you should probably at least mention the term "[dot product](https://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/math/dot/index.htm)" so that OP has a better idea of what to Google for  ;-)  Perhaps something like "taking the dot product of two normalized vectors gives the cosine of the angle between them"

Answer (score 0):

**The angle between two lines is the angle between direction vectors of the lines.**

Here's a formula:

[image]

You need to remove the `Z param` from the equation and then calculate your angle from the `cosine`.